# Logistic-Regression Jupyter notebook RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log second = np.multiply((1-y),np.log(1-h(x,theta)))

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, logistic-regression

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Creating your own Logistic Regression
Creating the functions:

These are just the definintions for the functions, we will use them later after reading in the data
Create the Hypothesis Function

```
#FILL IN THE CODE THAT IS MISSING 
def h(X,theta):  
z = x*theta.T
#np.exp(value) will evaluate e^(value)
sigmoid = 1/1+np.exp(-z)
return sigmoid
```

Create the Cost Function

```
#FILL IN THE CODE THAT IS MISSING
def J(theta, X, y):  

#convert theta, X, y to a np matrix using np.matrix(listName)
theta = np.matrix(theta)
X = np.matrix(X)
y = np.matrix(y)

#The first part of the Sum Function ylog(h(x,theta) use np.multiply(matrix1,matrix2)
z = X*theta.T
sigmoid = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
first = np.multiply(y, np.log(h(x,theta)))

#The second part of the Sum Function (1-y)log(1-h(x,theta)) use np.multiply(matrix1,matrix2)
second = np.multiply((1-y),np.log(1-h(x,theta)))

total = np.sum(first - second) / (len(X))

return total
```

Create the Gradient Function

```
 #FILL IN THE CODE THAT IS MISSING

 def G(theta, X_train, y_train):  

#Convert X_train, y_train, theta to a matrix using np.matrix(listName)
theta = np.matrix(theta)
X_train = np.matrix(X_train)
y_train = np.matrix(y_train)

parameters = int(theta.ravel().shape[1])
grad = np.zeros(parameters)

#Compute the error h(xtrain,theta) - ytrain
error = h(X_train,theta) - ytrain

for i in range(parameters):
    term = np.multiply(error, X_train[:,i])
    grad[i] = np.sum(term) / len(X_train)

return grad
```

Create a prediction function for a piece of data

```
#FILL IN THE CODE THAT IS MISSING
def predict(theta,xtest):

theta = np.matrix(theta)

#Calculate the probabilities of all the test data sent by calling the hypothesis function sending xtest and theta
probabilities = h(xtest,theta)

#Calculate the prediction based on the probabilities
predictions = []
for probability in probabilities:
    
    #prediction is equal to 1 if the probability is >= 0.5 otherwise prediction is equal to 0
    if probability >=0.5 :
        prediction = 1
    else:
        prediction = 0
    predictions.append(prediction)

return predictions
```

Create the Accuracy Function
Takes two arrays and compares the results to check how many are equal

```
def score(theta, xtest, ytest):
predictions = predict(theta, xtest)   
    
correct = 0
numValues = len(ytest)
for i in range(0,numValues):
    if predictions[i] == ytest[i]:
        correct = correct + 1

a = correct / numValues * 100
return a
```

Using the Functions:

Read all the data in from the ex2data1.txt that is included in your download. Store your data in regular python lists named:

x1 which represents the score on Exam 1 (First column)
x2 which represents the score on Exam 2 (2nd column)
y which respresents if they were accepted or not. 1 = accepted, 0 = not accepted (3rd Column)

```
#FILL IN THE CODE To Read in the data to x1, x2, y
import os
path = os.getcwd() + '\ex2data1.txt'

x1=[]
x2=[]
y=[]
file = open(path,"r")
while True:
line = file.readline()
if not line:
    break
else:
    values = line.split(",")
    x1.append(float(values[0]))
    x2.append(float(values[1]))
    y.append(float(values[2].rstrip("\n")))
file.close()
```

Get the size of the data set using the len(listName) function

```
#FILL IN THE CODE THAT IS MISSING
m1 = len(x1)
print(m1)
m2 = len(x2)
print(m2)
m3 = len(y)
print(m3)
```

Convert the x1 and x2 data to a np array using np.array(listName)

```
#FILL IN THE CODE THAT IS MISSING
x1 = np.array(x1)
x2 = np.array(x2)
```

Create an array of ones using np.ones((#ofRows,1))

```
#FILL IN THE CODE THAT IS MISSING
ones = np.ones((100,1))
```

Combine them together using np.column_stack((col1Name, col2Name, col3Name)). The ones are first, then x1, then x2

```
#FILL IN THE CODE THAT IS MISSING
x = np.column_stack((ones,x1,x2))
```

Convert the y data to the transpose of a np array (Needed for the matrix multiplication that the functions do)

```
y = np.array([y]).T
```

Create the theta array filled with zeros as the initial guesses using np.zeros(#ofWeights)

```
#FILL IN THE CODE THAT IS MISSING
theta = np.zeros(3)
print(theta)
```

Test the cost function

This is the original cost value with the theta values as 0
If your code is correct it should display approximately 0.69

```
 cost = J(theta,x,y)
 print(cost)
```

My output: nan

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
second = np.multiply((1-y),np.log(1-h(x,theta)))

This is what someone said I need to do:

Logistic regression

in the h function you need to type in the formulas for z and sigmoid exactly as they are written in the equations above it.

In the J function you need to calculate

first -> use -y as the first matrix, and use log (h(x,theta)) as the second matrix in the np multiplication

second -> use (1-y) as the first matrix and use log (1-h(x,theta)) as the second matrix in the multiplication

In the predict function

to calculate the probabilities you just call the h function and send xtest and theta to it

What went wrong?

answer clearly and show me with my code, please.